# php command line - chaining options for interpreter

Tags: php

I am trying to set the maximum execution time and maximum memory limit that a script can use via PHP command line:

```
 php -d max_execution_time=0 max_memory_limit=2048M some_script here
```

However this always gives me an error of:

```
Could not open input file: max_memory_limit=2048M
```

Why is this? How do I chain the two options?

Comment: It is redundant to set max_execution_time to 0. See [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). "When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By providing multiple -d switches:

```
php -d max_execution_time=0 -d max_memory_limit=2048M script.php
```

Comment: is it possible that a script needed more than X amount of memory to complete? If yes what will happen if I limit it like this